# Is there a word to describe feathers, scales, fur, hair, etc. on an animal

Tags: word-choice, terminology, animals

Is there a word to describe or reference feathers, scales, fur, hair, exoskeleton (maybe?), etc. on a creature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is called an ***integument.***

> *integument*, in biology, network of features that forms the covering of an organism.
>
> Among unicellular organisms, such as bacteria and protozoans, the integument corresponds to the cell membrane and any secreted coating that the organism produces. In most invertebrate animals a layer (or layers) of surface (epithelial) cells—often with additional secreted coatings—constitutes the integument. Among the vertebrates **the boundary covering**—with a variety of derived elements such as **scales, feathers, and hair**—has assumed the complexity of an organ system, **the integumentary system.**
>
> <sub>http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/289723/integument</sub>

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

It can be called *integumentary system* or *body covering* also. Here is a detailed list of integuments from the University of British Columbia, Department of Zoology:

http://www.zoology.ubc.ca/~millen/vertebrate/Bio204_Labs/Lab_2__Integument..html

Comment: Also: http://www.encyclopedia.com/doc/1G2-3400500293.html

Comment: Note: You said "animal" in the title but integument applies to any organism. You said "creature" in the question body though. [Maybe it would be better if you say "organism" in the title.]

Answer (score 1):

You can try "***coat***", but it would probably need "*of armor*" for the exoskeleton. (However, it is used to describe outer coverings of many kinds.)